# Is there a special name for expressions of the form $(1+f(x))$ where $|f(x)|<1$?

Tags: terminology

I know that a binomial expression like $(1+x)$ with $|x|<1$, when raised to some power $p$ can be expressed as a Binomial Series as in Equation (1) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

PURPOSE: I am using expressions of the form $(1+f(x))^p$ (and their "binomial" expansions) in a computer program which performs various operations (add, multiply, divide, raise-to-power) on algebraic expressions, resulting in thousands of terms.  It would be useful (for communication) to have a name for this form of expression. If there is an existing name that would be better than inventing a new one.

Comment: How do you mean that $1$ is the largest of those terms? What hapens for $x=0.9$, for instance?

Comment: series with value $1$ at the origin?

Comment: @Arthur Good point! That was a bad example I gave. I have modified my example.

Comment: Series with constant coefficient $1$?

Comment: Your question is still unclear. I suspect that even were you to clarify it, there is no special name for the kind of series you have in mind. You could [edit] the question to tell us why you need a name.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker I have modifed the question and text.